# Add to Listbox if cell value contains specific string

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, range

I am trying to add data to a Listbox on a Userform, based on the value of the the Cell in column C of the range that is searched. If the cell in column C contains a certain string I would like it to be added to the Listbox.

The below code is as far as I have got but it is returning an empty Listbox with no error.

```
Private Sub OptionButton12_Click()

Dim I As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim searchString As String

searchString = "LISTBOXENTRY"

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Plybooks.ListBox1.Clear
For I = 1 To lastRow
    If Cells(I, 3).Value = searchString Then
        Plybooks.ListBox1.AddItem Range("A" & I)
    End If
Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: For starters you should add sheet references in your loop in case a different sheet is active. Where is this code?

Comment: This code is on an OptionButton that is on the Userform with the Listbox. Code amended to reference ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") but returning the same

Comment: Have you checked the value of `lastrow`?

Comment: If you are on the correct sheet and `lastRow` calculated for A:A returns correct, then are there the word "LISTBOXENTRY" in the range where the code is looking for it? I mean, in proper case. VBA is case sensitive like default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added cell values in ranges over multiple sheets if cell contains certain value, using the following:

```
Public Sub PlybookListbox()

'Clear fields before start
Plybooks.ListBox1.MultiSelect = 0
Plybooks.ListBox1.Clear
Plybooks.ListBox1.Value = ""
Plybooks.ListBox1.MultiSelect = 2

Dim AllAreas(2) As Range, Idx As Integer, MyCell As Range, TargetRange As Range
Dim lastrowFrontWing As Long
Dim lastrowNose As Long
Dim lastrowBargeboard As Long

lastrowFrontWing = Worksheets("Front Wing").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
lastrowNose = Worksheets("Nose").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
lastrowBargeboard = Worksheets("Bargeboard & SPV").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    Set AllAreas(0) = Worksheets("Front Wing").Range("c6:c" & lastrowFrontWing)
    Set AllAreas(1) = Worksheets("Nose").Range("c6:c" & lastrowNose)
    Set AllAreas(2) = Worksheets("Bargeboard & SPV").Range("c6:c" & lastrowBargeboard)

Plybooks.ListBox1.Clear

For Idx = 0 To 2
    For Each MyCell In AllAreas(Idx).Cells
        If InStr(1, MyCell.Value, "(FS)") > 0 Then
            Plybooks.ListBox1.AddItem MyCell.Value
        End If
    Next MyCell
Next Idx

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the script below and please let me know if it works!

based on your script above, I assumed some of the dataframe dimensions. please let me know if it is not correct so I can tweak it.

I assumed you are working on first sheet (sheets(1)), and col C is the column you are using for the value check against the "searchString"  variable. (if true, append the value in listbox1)

Thanks

```
Private Sub OptionButton12_Click()

Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim searchString As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sRng As Range
Dim cel As Range

'assign current wb into wb workbook object
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

'assign str you want to search into variable
searchString = "LISTBOXENTRY"

'find last row number in colC (3) using crow function. (assuming you want to do a check on every cell listed in column C)
lastRow = crow(1, 3)

plybooks.listbox1.Clear

'assign range object using dataframe dimensions based on row 1 col C (lbound), to lastrow col3 (ubound)
With wb.Sheets(1)

    Set sRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(trow, 3))
    
End With

'loops through each cel
For Each cel In sRng

    If cel.Value = searchString Then
        
        'adds item  into listbox1 if conditional statement is True
        plybooks.listbox1.AddItem Item:=cel.Value
    
    Else
    End If

Next cel

End Sub


Private Function crow(s As Variant, c As Integer)

    crow = Sheets(s).Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```